# Django ModelForm и динамический extra field

Tags: python, django

**Update:**
Вопрос изменен в сторону укорачивания согласно замечаний.

```py
class MultipleTableForm(forms.ModelForm):
    objects = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=((),)
    )

    class Meta:
        fields = ['objects']

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(self)
        choices=[
                (model_cls.__name__, model_cls._meta.verbose_name)
                for model_cls in self.multiple_table_model.fields_names.keys()
            ]
        self.fields['objects']._choices = choices
        self.fields['objects'].choices = choices

class IndividualEntityForm(MultipleTableForm):
    multiple_table_model = Subject

    class Meta:
        model = IndividualEntity
        fields = MultipleTableForm.Meta.fields + ['first_name', 'last_name']
```

Тестируем.

```py
>>> from subject.forms.subject_form import IndividualEntityForm as IEF
>>> form = IEF()
>>> form.fields['objects']._choices
[('IndividualEntity', 'Физическое лицо'), ('LegalEntity', 'Юридическое лицо')]
>>> form.fields['objects'].choices
[('IndividualEntity', 'Физическое лицо'), ('LegalEntity', 'Юридическое лицо')]
>>> form.as_p()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "E:\django_projects\opengisrepo\venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 304, in as_p
    errors_on_separate_row=True,
  File "E:\django_projects\opengisrepo\venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 202, in _html_output
    top_errors = self.non_field_errors()  # Errors that should be displayed above all fields.
  File "E:\django_projects\opengisrepo\venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 313, in non_field_errors
    return self.errors.get(NON_FIELD_ERRORS, self.error_class(error_class='nonfield'))
  File "E:\django_projects\opengisrepo\venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 180, in errors
    self.full_clean()
  File "E:\django_projects\opengisrepo\venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 381, in full_clean
    self._clean_fields()
  File "E:\django_projects\opengisrepo\venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 393, in _clean_fields
    value = field.widget.value_from_datadict(self.data, self.files, self.add_prefix(name))
  File "E:\django_projects\opengisrepo\venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py", line 258, in value_from_datadict
    return data.get(name)
AttributeError: 'IndividualEntityForm' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Хочется. Добавить в форму динамический `choiceField`. Чтобы сам список значений строился согласно атрибута класса `multiple_table_model`.

Comment: Можете покороче выразить суть проблемы? Вряд ли кто-то станет разбирать простыню вашего кода.

Comment: Как устроено — у ModelForm и всех его наследников прописан специальный метакласс для форм, который творит всякую тёмную магию с `objects` и остальными полями; у вашего класса `MultipleTableForm` в первых двух вариантах такого метакласса не оказалось, поэтому и магии не случилось. // Как сделать — я не понял, что именно нужно сделать-то, вопрос непонятен. Зачем вам вообще нужен `IFF.objects`?

Comment: @m0nte-cr1st0. Да, согласен. Слишком длинный пост оказался, можно было короче сформировать вопрос. Я к сожалению не нашел волшебной кнопки редактирования вопроса.

Comment: @andreymal. Необходимо в форму добавить поле-список который определяется как раз `objects`. При этом сам список для `objects` для каждой дочерней формы разный. Хотелось бы написать код который будет или при инициализации класса или при инициализации экземпляра класса определял как раз сам список согласно атрибута `multiple_table_model` дочернего класса.

Comment: @andreymal. Я добавил `Meta` класс в `MultipleTableForm`, в экземпляре класса в `fields` есть поле `objects`, но все равно при обращении form.as_p() происходит исключение `AttributeError: 'IndividualEntityForm' object has no attribute 'get'`

Comment: class Meta - это не метакласс, это просто класс внутри класса с названием Meta, который ничего магического не делает. Метакласс - это совершенно другая штука, почитайте об этом в интернете

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтож решил вопрос через функции фабрики. Делюсь, может кому поможет, также может будут предложения для улучшения.

```py
from django import forms
from django.forms import modelform_factory

from subject.models.subject import IndividualEntity, LegalEntity, Subject


def addfields_modelform_factory(
        form_class_name: str,
        model_class: object,
        additional_form_attributes: dict={},
        modelform_factory_kwargs: dict={}
    ):

    form_class = type('NewForm', (forms.ModelForm,), additional_form_attributes)

    return type(
        form_class_name,
        (
            modelform_factory(
                model=model_class,
                form=form_class,
                **modelform_factory_kwargs
            ),
        ),
        {}
    )

def multiple_table_form_factory(
    form_class_name: str,
    multiple_table_model: object,
    model_class: object,
    additional_form_attributes: dict={},
    modelform_factory_kwargs: dict={}
):
    additional_form_attributes['multiple_table_model'] = multiple_table_model
    additional_form_attributes['objects'] = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=[
                (model_cls.__name__, model_cls._meta.verbose_name)
                for model_cls in multiple_table_model.fields_names.keys()
            ],
    )
    if isinstance(modelform_factory_kwargs['fields'], list):
        modelform_factory_kwargs['fields'].insert(0, 'objects')

    return addfields_modelform_factory(
        form_class_name=form_class_name,
        model_class=model_class,
        additional_form_attributes=additional_form_attributes,
        modelform_factory_kwargs=modelform_factory_kwargs
    )

IndividualEntityForm = multiple_table_form_factory(
    form_class_name='IndividualEntityForm',
    multiple_table_model=Subject,
    model_class=IndividualEntity,
    additional_form_attributes={},
    modelform_factory_kwargs={
        'fields': ['first_name', 'last_name'],
    }
)
```

Тестируем

```
>>> form = IndividualEntityForm()
>>> form.fields
OrderedDict([('objects', <django.forms.fields.ChoiceField object at 0x050D3FD0>), ('first_name', <django.forms.fields.CharField object at 0x05100090>), ('last_name', <django.forms.fields.CharField object at 0x051000D0>)])
>>> form.fields['objects']._choices
[('IndividualEntity', 'Физическое лицо'), ('LegalEntity', 'Юридическое лицо')]
>>> form.fields['objects'].choices
[('IndividualEntity', 'Физическое лицо'), ('LegalEntity', 'Юридическое лицо')]
>>> form.as_p()
'<p><label for="id_objects">Objects:</label> <select name="objects" id="id_objects">\n  <option value="IndividualEntity">Физическое лицо</option>\n\n  <option value="LegalEntity">Юридическое лицо</option>\n\n</select></p>\n<p><label for="id_first_name">Имя:</label> <input type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="75" required id="id_first_name"></p>\n<p><label for="id_last_name">Фамилия:</label> <input type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="75" required id="id_last_name"></p>'
```